# Dense subset in $L^p $ spaces.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\mathbf {P}$ is a probability measure on $(\mathbf {R},\mathcal{B}).$ Show that for any $p\in[1,\infty]$, the class of all bounded continuous functions is a dense subset of $L^p (\mathbf {R},\mathcal{B},\mathbf {P}) $

I have proved it for $p\in[1,\infty)$, in the process I have shown that indicator function of any measurable set can be arbitrarily approximated by bounded continuous functions. But I am struggling in the $\infty $ case. Any help please.

Here $||f||_\infty=$ inf $\{\lambda : P (|f|>\lambda)=0\}$

Comment: Isn't this obviously false? Consider $1_{[0,1]}$. Any continuous function $f$ will have $||f-1_{[0,1]}||_\infty \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You are struggling because it is false. If it were true, all $L^\infty$ functions would be continuous.

Comment: My result for indicator functions were also proved for $p\neq \infty$